# Error cannot read property of undefined using node.js with mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I keep getting this error cannot read property of undefined when the password does not match what is is the database however if it is the same its all fine.

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let router = express.Router();
let users = require('./users.js');
let ejs = require('ejs');
let pg = require('pg');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let mysql = require('mysql');

let connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost",
user: "root",
password: "password",
port: 3306,
database: "nodeapp2"
 });
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/input', function(req,res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/input.html');
});
app.get('/login', function (req,res) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/login.html');
});


app.post('/logincred', function(req, res) {

console.log('req.body');
console.log(req.body);



connection.query("SELECT password FROM logins WHERE password = '"+req.body.password+"'",function(err, result){
    if (err)
        throw err;
        if (result[0].password === req.body.password){
            console.log(req.body.password);
            console.log('password accepted');
            res.redirect('/');
            res.end()
        } else {
            res.redirect('/login')
            res.write('login failed');
            res.end()
        }
});

});
```

If I input the wrong password and I hit the else clause that when I get the error and I am not sure why.

Comment: Hello, a few things jump out as issues here :). First, you are vulnerable to SQL injection with that query. Second does your SQL handler throw on an empty result? If not most likely you need to check if the result exists before trying to access a property of it.

Comment: It is only a local test script since I am learning node and express for work so SQL injection is not a concern here however I appreciate bringing it up for me to be aware of. The result that is returned is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the variable `res` is not declared anywhere in the scope of the anonymous callback function. You're using  `result` in the if condition `result[0].password === req.body.password` but using `res` in the if/else clauses. Try using `result` instead of `res`?

Comment: It seems they are interchangeable as the outcome was the same after changing that.